# how to add images to dialog flow chat bot in android studio

Tags: dialogflow-es

`I'm using dialog flow for chat bot in my app. I've tried to put some images for chat bot to send it to user. It works fine and appears in dialog flow simulator but it doesn't  work and nothing appear in my app. Any help? I'm using android studio. I've tried to change the code so many time the app works but the same problem

The image shows the result in my app and the result in dialog flow simulator
 [image to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXKOw.png)

```
package com.example.lmdinalarbi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.github.bassaer.chatmessageview.model.Message;
import com.github.bassaer.chatmessageview.view.ChatView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import ai.api.AIServiceException;
import ai.api.RequestExtras;
import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.android.AIDataService;
import ai.api.android.GsonFactory;
import ai.api.model.AIContext;
import ai.api.model.AIError;
import ai.api.model.AIEvent;
import ai.api.model.AIRequest;
import ai.api.model.AIResponse;
import ai.api.model.Metadata;
import ai.api.model.Result;
import ai.api.model.Status;





public class chatbotamali extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,View.OnClickListener

{
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private Gson gson = GsonFactory.getGson();
    private AIDataService aiDataService;
    private ChatView chatView;
    private User myAccount;
    private User amali;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatbotamali);



        initChatView();

        //Language, Dialogflow Client access token
        final LanguageConfig config = new LanguageConfig("JavaScript",  "239001d3094444b390e30d3e3ea6832bwwww"
                ,

                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System

        );
        initService(config);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("AM ALI");
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //new message
        final Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .setUser(myAccount)
                .setRight(true)
                .setText(chatView.getInputText())
                .hideIcon(true)
                .build();
        //Set to chat view
        chatView.send(message);
        sendRequest(chatView.getInputText());
        //Reset edit text
        chatView.setInputText("");
    }

    private void sendRequest(String text) {
        Log.d(TAG, text);
        final String queryString = String.valueOf(text);
        final String eventString = null;
        final String contextString = null;

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(queryString) && TextUtils.isEmpty(eventString)) {
            onError(new AIError(getString(R.string.non_empty_query)));
            return;
        }

        new AiTask().execute(queryString, eventString, contextString);
    }

    public class AiTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, AIResponse> {
        private AIError aiError;

        @Override
        protected AIResponse doInBackground(final String... params) {
            final AIRequest request = new AIRequest();
            String query = params[0];
            String event = params[1];
            String context = params[2];

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)){
                request.setQuery(query);
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(event)){
                request.setEvent(new AIEvent(event));
            }

            RequestExtras requestExtras = null;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(context)) {
                final List<AIContext> contexts = Collections.singletonList(new AIContext(context));
                requestExtras = new RequestExtras(contexts, null);
            }

            try {
                return aiDataService.request(request, requestExtras);
            } catch (final AIServiceException e) {
                aiError = new AIError(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final AIResponse response) {
            if (response != null) {
                onResult(response);
            } else {
                onError(aiError);
            }
        }
    }


    private void onResult(final AIResponse response) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Variables
                gson.toJson(response);
                final Status status = response.getStatus();
                final Result result = response.getResult();
                final String speech = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                final Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();
                final HashMap<String, JsonElement> params = result.getParameters();

                // Logging
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult");
                Log.i(TAG, "Received success response");
                Log.i(TAG, "Status code: " + status.getCode());
                Log.i(TAG, "Status type: " + status.getErrorType());
                Log.i(TAG, "Resolved query: " + result.getResolvedQuery());
                Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + result.getAction());
                Log.i(TAG, "Speech: " + speech);

                if (metadata != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Intent id: " + metadata.getIntentId());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Intent name: " + metadata.getIntentName());
                }

                if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Parameters: ");
                    for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %s",
                                entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
                    }
                }

                //Update view to bot says
                final Message receivedMessage = new Message.Builder()
                        .setUser(amali)
                        .setRight(false)
                        .setText(speech)
                        .build();
                chatView.receive(receivedMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    private void onError(final AIError error) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e(TAG,error.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void initChatView() {
        int myId = 0;
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tunis);
        String myName = "wledelmdina";
        myAccount = new User(myId, myName, icon);

        int botId = 1;
        String botName = "amali";
        amali = new User(botId, botName, icon);

        chatView = findViewById(R.id.chat_view);
        chatView.setRightBubbleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green500));
        chatView.setLeftBubbleColor(Color.RED);
        chatView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.aidialog_background));
        chatView.setSendButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lightBlue500));
        chatView.setSendIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_send);
        chatView.setRightMessageTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        chatView.setLeftMessageTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        chatView.setUsernameTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        chatView.setSendTimeTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        chatView.setDateSeparatorColor(Color.GRAY);
        chatView.setInputTextHint("new message...");
        chatView.setMessageMarginTop(5);
        chatView.setMessageMarginBottom(5);
        chatView.setOnClickSendButtonListener(this);
    }

    private void initService(final LanguageConfig languageConfig) {
        final AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages lang =
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.fromLanguageTag(languageConfig.getLanguageCode());
        final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration(languageConfig.getAccessToken(),
                lang,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
        aiDataService = new AIDataService(this, config);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NotNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.Eldmina) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("VALUE_SEND","this data Send");

            startActivity(intent);



            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.souk) {


            Intent intent=new Intent(this,elsoukmenu.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("VALUE_SEND","this data Send");

            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.wled) {


            Intent intent=new Intent(this,wledelmdina.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("VALUE_SEND","this data Send");

            startActivity(intent);


        } else if (id == R.id.profile) {

        }

        else if (id == R.id.about) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,aboutuss.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("VALUE_SEND","this data Send");

            startActivity(intent);

        }

        else if (id == R.id.report) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,wledelmdinamenu.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("VALUE_SEND","this data Send");

            startActivity(intent);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

[build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYIZc.png)

Comment: Create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can u explain what is that

Comment: It's explained in link - Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

Comment: thank you for the advice , i past my code